# QFileSystemModel with FTP

Tags: qt, qfilesystemmodel

I have the listing of a FTP server as a list of strings. Is there a way to give the list to the QFileSystemModel and display the files without existing on the local system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, at least not with the `QFileSystemModel`. That's not what it was design for. It directly uses the filesystem to create and manage the model, and cannot use other sources.

What you can do is to implement your own [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html). It's not complicated to create the model itself. However, getting file icons is a little more difficult.

For the file icons, have a look at this post: [Qt 4.8 - QFileIconProvider, Getting icon for non-existent file (based on extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946601/qt-4-8-qfileiconprovider-getting-icon-for-non-existent-file-based-on-extensi)

Since Qt does not support loading icons for non existent files, they have to be loaded using native APIs. The link is a solution for windows.